# Kali linux doesnt show new updates and upgrades

Tags: kali-linux, upgrade, dist-upgrade

I have my old 2016.2 kali version on usb stick.I installed it on dual boot.
I ran `uname -a` in terminal and got output: `Linux kali 4.6.0-kali1-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) i686 GNU/Linux` which i suppose is kali 2016.2. But when i do `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` it doesn't install anything. And 2017.1 is out.

Comment: I myself had faced this issue and the only solution I found was a fresh install (by formatting the disk) using a live USB or DVD. That is, if you want a new distribution/release feel (unlike other linux distributions). Otherwise, a kernel and package upgrades would technically be upgraded as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276425/how-to-upgrade-kali-linux).

Answer (score 0):

You have first to instruct `apt` that it has to switch to your new version by properly editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` and files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` (i.e. changing the old version codename to the new one).